# Prevent Class From Sharing Sub-Class in Python?

Tags: python-2.7, class

I have the following code, while it isn't my actual code it shows the problem I'm having:

```
class SubObject:
    value = None

class Object:
    subObject = SubObject()

object0 = Object()
object0.subObject.value = 'hello'

object1 = Object()
object1.subObject.value = 'world'

print object0.subObject.value + ' ' + object1.subObject.value
```

I have a class `SubObject` that is used in another class `Object` but when I create two `Object` variables they share the same instance of `SubObject`. This has been causing me plenty of frustration and my actual code really needs the class-in-class, so refactoring into one massive class isn't really what I want to do.

Running the above code in python 2 prints `world world`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize the data members of the classes using proper constructors. This would be one way to solve this:

```
class SubObject:
    def __init__ (self):
      self.value = None

class Object:
    def __init__ (self):
      self.subObject = SubObject()

object0 = Object()
object0.subObject.value = 'hello'

object1 = Object()
object1.subObject.value = 'world'

print object0.subObject.value + ' ' + object1.subObject.value
```

The output for this program is:
hello world

Comment: can we alias constructors or do they have to be `__init__`?

Comment: An added note: variables in the constructor are accessible by functions in the class.

Comment: The __init__ function represents a constructor in python. When a new instance of the class gets created, python transfers control to that function along with the given parameters.

Comment: You will be able to access the data members of the class from a member function only if you pass in the instance of the object to the function (which is what "self" means). Most object oriented languages pass this as a hidden parameter, but in python you have to pass it explicitly.